# No such element in iterator

Tags: java, loops, iterator

I have a simple code where I need to iterate through a list and write it in XML.
But problem is that sometimes my tags exceeds and values are less than tags so I want to write there a "-" or something like that.
 But I am facing problem while doing this. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
while(iter1.hasNext()){
            for (Object elementKey  : tags) {
Here is the problem---->String value = iter1.next();
                        String element = (String) elementKey;
                        if(value!=null){
                        out.write("<"+element+">"+value+"</"+element+">");
                        }
                        else
                            out.write("<"+element+">"+"-"+"</"+element+">");

                        }

                    }
```

When Iterator doesn't have anything it is giving me no such element exception.
I have to call iter1.next() inside for loop because for  one iteration of for loop I have several values by iterator.
 Like you can say I have 60 element in for loop and for these 60 element I have only 56 values these values I am getting from iterator. Somebody tell me a good data structure for that? What should I do?

Comment: What are the tags holding and what is in  iter1, are they supposed to be matching list of equal size? If so you may want to use a map or a list of tuples/pairs(but java doesn't include any so you need to find or write some)

Comment: An example of what you're trying to achieve may help. Without knowing more, I'd say you need a better data structure (perhaps a collection of value-element pairs or similar) before you start iterating over it.

Comment: Thanks to all, even I didn't get the right answer but I fixed my code by own.

Answer (score 1):

You execute the `iter1.next()` several times (because it is in the for loop) for each '`hasNext()`' call you do. To fix this you need to move the `iter1.next()` outsize the for loop.

Comment: I know that but what is the solution how can I get what I want

Comment: Hey I have some need like that, that I have to put iter1.next in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `iter1.next();` in the `for each` loop for `tags`, therefore it may be called several times while you called `iter1.hasNext()` only once!

You may want to declare your variable outside the `for each` loop:

```
while(iter1.hasNext()){
    String value = iter1.next(); //Call to "next()" here!
    for (Object elementKey  : tags) {
        String element = (String) elementKey;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `iter1.next()` for each Object in the tags collection. This will cause the iterator to end before you expect it to.

Put `String value = iter1.next();` outside the loop of 'tags'.

Answer (score 0):

You do next() in a loop, so you try to fetch the `next` multiple times after checking if there is 1 next item for sure.

Maybe you should make a String instance before your loop and then use this?

```
while(iter1.hasNext()){
          String next = iter1.next()
            for (Object elementKey  : tags) {
              String value = next;
              ...
```